# Encoding value Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I have one problem with enconding variable in Jmeter.
I extract value from previosly response body and save to the value,
defined such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvyWE.png.
sigAlg: "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"

According during using next POST method request JMETER code special characters such like as %,/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABfFP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using "Body Data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, if your setup is different - make sure not to check `URL Encode?` box next to the parameter name.

[image]

For the future: if you have doubts regarding proper configuration of the HTTP Request sampler - the easiest solution would be just recording the request from your browser using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)